# Community eval — Feb 2013

Tags: discussion

Some of you may have noticed we had a community evaluation last week. Here are the results. You can comment in this thread.

`Ex Sa NI sc`
 23  16  1  22   [Would Harry still be a Parselmouth at the end of the Deathly Hallows?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/27613/would-harry-still-be-a-parselmouth-at-the-end-of-the-deathly-hallows)
 28  17  1  27   [How did the Millennium Falcon get from Hoth to Bespin without hyperdrive?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/27687/how-did-the-millennium-falcon-get-from-hoth-to-bespin-without-hyperdrive)
 29  15  0  29   [Where did J.R.R. Tolkien state that Arwen suggested that Frodo be allowed to sail West?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/27986/where-did-j-r-r-tolkien-state-that-arwen-suggested-that-frodo-be-allowed-to-sai)
  8  27  5   3   [Do Powell and Donovan experience relativistic time dilation, in 'Escape!'?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28007/do-powell-and-donovan-experience-relativistic-time-dilation-in-escape)
 15  22  7   8   [What's the range of Magneto's powers?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28041/whats-the-range-of-magnetos-powers)
  6  20  9 ‒3   [Who is to credit for Aaron Satie's wisdom?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28146/who-is-to-credit-for-aaron-saties-wisdom)
 34  15  1  33   [What does Yoda wear around his neck?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28235/what-does-yoda-wear-around-his-neck)
 25  19  2  23   [Comic female protagonist, pretty sure a goddess?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28280/desperate-to-find-comic-features-female-protagonist-pretty-sure-a-goddess)
 12  19  4   8   [How can the prophet fail to anticipate some events?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28619/how-can-the-prophet-fail-to-anticipate-some-events)
 22  14  0  22   [Fringe: how could September or any other man from the future catch gun bullets in the air?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28746/fringe-how-could-september-or-any-other-man-from-the-future-catch-gun-bullets-i)

<sub>`Ex`/`Sa`/`NI`: number of “excellent/satisfactory/needs improvement” ratings</sub> 
 <sup>`sc`: total score</sup>

Comment: What does this mean in terms of the site, and how do we compare to other SE sites?

Comment: @aSlytherin I don't know about comparisons between sites, I only have the figures for a few and the sample sizes are small. Overall it looks like we consider that we did very well for 6 questions, ok for 3 and bad for 1. Nobody seems really sure of how to interpret these results for a graduated side, this was more of an experiment.

Comment: I forgot; Do the ratings refer to the quality of the *question* or the *answers*?

Comment: @bitmask Both. Basically: Ex=you can't find it elsewhere; Sa=you won't be disappointed; NI=skip it.

Comment: @Gilles: I was just wondering how much I am to blame (myself) for us receiving one "crap" evaluation. The question itself seems decently up-voted with +9-0 votes, which doesn't seem to match the eval result.

Comment: @bitmask You mean [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28146/who-is-to-credit-for-aaron-saties-wisdom)? I think the question is fine, but the answer doesn't seem authoritative.